# Assign null to repeater's DataSource before changing its source

Tags: c#

I have a very old tick: whenever I'm setting the datasource for a Repeater I always set it first to null.

```
this.rptMyRepeater.DataSource = null; //is this line necessary?
this.rptMyRepeater.DataSource = pNewSource;
this.rptMyRepeater.DataBind();
```

I don't even remember why I started doing that but I'm sure I had some ugly issues associated with data-bound objects not binding properly if I didn't assign null first.

Years have passed and new framework versions came, maybe it was some old bug or maybe I was plain wrong.

Is it necessary to assign null to data-bound objects DataSource property before setting it?

Comment: why not try it and see what the results yield..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE if I try without that line it will work (I suposse), but I think the problems I had where rare and conditional escenarios, so a single test wont answer my question.

Comment: It doesn't hurt it to set / assign the variable to null personally I think it's a good thing to do but that's just my own personal coding style and or preference

Comment: "I have a very old tick" - squarsh it before it starts sucking your blood! If you mean that the DataSource has already been set once (potentially) so you want to toggle it off before re-running the query, likely with a different parameter or set of parameters, I can see why you ask the question - in fact, that's why I found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, the Ray Cheng's comments on Jeppe's answer and waiting for someone with evidence of this being neccesary, I conclude the answer is no, it is not neccesary to assign null to the DataSource before reassigning it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what the `null` assignment would be good for when you're going to reassign the same member in the next line.

Is `DataSource` a property with a `set` accessor that introduces funny side effects?

Comment: Depends on the binding source, setting `DataSource` property may trigger other events to fire. In my opinion, it's not a good design. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @RayCheng I have no experience with `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater` (maybe I shouldn't have sent an answer, then), but if you say it's poorly designed, I will not rule out the possibility that the class behaves "better" when you set the property twice :-(